# Convert query from MySQL to SQL Server (include GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm trying to convert this MySQL query to SQL Server, but I do not know much about SQL Server

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Table1 AS T1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 
    ON T1.Column1 = T2.ColumnX 
WHERE 
  T1.ColumnY = 'xxxx' 
GROUP BY 
  T1.Column1
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Your query will not work in newer (and SQL standard compliant) versions of MySQL as well.

Comment: "killing me" isn't an error message. What actual issue are you experiencing? I'm going to guess it's because you need to specify all the non-aggregate columns in your group by clause.

Comment: That query will run in SQL Server but what are you trying to achieve exactly? Since you aren't doing any aggregations, this is similar to `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: In MySQL this query would return random data assuming it was allowed to run at all. From [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html): `If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries` and `If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled ... the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still haven't told us what you believe the problem to be. What difficulty are you facing, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is just an erroneous query, because you are using `select *` with `group by`.  This query uses a MySQL extension.  And, the default settings in more recent versions of MySQL would generate an error.

Here is one method for converting this to SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES * 
FROM Table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN
     Table2 AS T2 
      ON T1.Column1 = T2.ColumnX 
WHERE T1.ColumnY = 'xxxx' 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Column1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ;
```

Probably a better method (from a performance perspective) uses a lateral join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 T1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) T2.*
      FROM Table2 T2 
      WHERE T1.Column1 = T2.ColumnX 
     ) T2
WHERE T1.ColumnY = 'xxxx' ;
```

Both of these choose arbitrary rows from `Table2` when there is more than one match.